# Multiples resolutionStrategy in build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I need to add two resolutrionStrategy into configurations.all, in build.gradle

The new resolutionStrategy is the following:

```
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
    if (requested.group == "org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle" && requested.name == "cardinalmobilesdk") {
        useVersion("2.2.7-2")
        because("user data consent per Google's Data Safety Policy")
    }
}
```

but my current configurations.all is the following:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
}
```

so, how can I add the new resolutionStrategy without affecting the current?
I think this can be a good way, but I don't know how to check if is correct

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
    
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle" && requested.name == "cardinalmobilesdk") {
            useVersion("2.2.7-2")
            because("user data consent per Google's Data Safety Policy")
        }
    }
}
```